# MethodError Mystery: Unexpected Third Argument in Constructor Call After Julia Kernel Upgrade (1.5 to 1.9)

Tags: julia

I am trying to get some code to run on a newer julia kernel version (jump from 1.5 to 1.9) including newer package versions so I have to debug a lot of function arguments.

I am hardstuck on a very specific one:

When calling

```
A = constructor(b, c)
```

running the code fails with the following method error:

```
MethodError: no method matching Constructor(::b,::c,::d).

Closest candidates are:
    Constructor(::b,::c)
```

When printing typeof(b) and typeof(c) before the constructor call, it is showing the correct types.

**Why is there suddenly a third argument showing up in the MethodError?** **How can I call the constructor without this mysterious third argument?**

In case this is a problem with the specific package containing the constructor in question, here is my code:

```
println(SimpleGraph(0))
println(typeof(SimpleGraph(0)))
println(typeof([]))
new_graph = EmbeddedGraph(SimpleGraph(0),[])
```

Before this code I did:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add(EmbeddedGraphs)
Pkg.add(Graphs)
using EmbeddedGraphs
using Graphs
```

and the output is:

```
SimpleGraph{Int64}(0, Vector{Int64}[])
SimpleGraph{Int64}
Vector{Any}

MethodError: no method matching EmbeddedGraph(::SimpleGraph{Int64}, ::Vector{Any}, ::EmbeddedGraphs.var"#6#7"{Distances.Euclidean})

Closest candidates are:
  EmbeddedGraph(::SimpleGraph{T}, ::Vector{Vector{Float64}}, ::Function) where T<:Integer
   @ EmbeddedGraphs ~/.julia/packages/EmbeddedGraphs/hxyfT/src/embeddedgraph.jl:19
  EmbeddedGraph(::SimpleGraph, ::Array)
   @ EmbeddedGraphs ~/.julia/packages/EmbeddedGraphs/hxyfT/src/embeddedgraph.jl:23
  EmbeddedGraph(::SimpleGraph, ::Array, ::Distances.Metric)
   @ EmbeddedGraphs ~/.julia/packages/EmbeddedGraphs/hxyfT/src/embeddedgraph.jl:24
  ...


Stacktrace:
 [1] EmbeddedGraph(graph::SimpleGraph{Int64}, vertexpos::Vector{Any}, distance::Distances.Euclidean)
   @ EmbeddedGraphs ~/.julia/packages/EmbeddedGraphs/hxyfT/src/embeddedgraph.jl:24
 [2] EmbeddedGraph(graph::SimpleGraph{Int64}, vertexpos::Vector{Any})
   @ EmbeddedGraphs ~/.julia/packages/EmbeddedGraphs/hxyfT/src/embeddedgraph.jl:23
 [3] regenerate_graph(vertices::Matrix{Float64}, grids_weights_col_ptr::Vector{Int64}, grids_weights_row_val::Vector{Int64})
   @ Main ./In[90]:8
 [4] load_static_test_case(id::String)
   @ Main ./In[68]:9
 [5] simulate_grid(r::Int64)
   @ Main ./In[72]:4
 [6] top-level scope
   @ In[91]:14
```

Where is that `::EmbeddedGraphs.var"#6#7"{Distances.Euclidean})` coming from? I am so confused!

**Addon:**

When running

```
@code_warntype EmbeddedGraph(SimpleGraph(0),[])
```

I get the following output:

```
MethodInstance for EmbeddedGraph(::SimpleGraph{Int64}, ::Vector{Any})
  from EmbeddedGraph(graph::SimpleGraph, vertexpos::Array) @ EmbeddedGraphs ~/.julia/packages/EmbeddedGraphs/hxyfT/src/embeddedgraph.jl:23
Arguments
  #self#::Type{EmbeddedGraph}
  graph::SimpleGraph{Int64}
  vertexpos::Vector{Any}
Body::Union{}
1 ─     EmbeddedGraphs.EmbeddedGraph(graph, vertexpos, EmbeddedGraphs.euclidean)
└──     Core.Const(:(return %1))
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a change in one of these packages, not in Julia (although e.g. latest Graphs.jl demands Julia >= 1.6, so Pkg would install an older one on 1.5). Unless someone here knows these packages, I would suggest making an issue at https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/Graphs.jl/issues to ask what needs changing in your code. Alternatively, you may be able to `pin` the packages to old versions on new Julia, which ought to allow your old code to run.